# Display array content from a for-loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, closures, push

I'm trying to show one number from randomTable for 8sec, 1by1. Sadly it's doesnt show anything at all.

```
    var numberTable = [];
    var randomTable = [];

    $('#pooling').append('<div id="box"> </div>');

    for (var i=1;i<=32;i++) {
        numberTable.push(i);
    }

    for (var i=0;i<8;i++) {
        (function (e) {
            randomTable.push(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (32 - e)));
            numberTable.splice(e,1);
            $('#box').replaceWith('<div id = "box>' + randomTable[e] + '</div>');
            $('#box').show(0).delay(8000).hide(0);
        })(i);
    }
```

When I remove 2nd for-loop it show empty #box, but with this loop it doesn't create this div at all. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what your intention is, but maybe this helps:

```js
var numberTable = [];
var randomTable = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
  numberTable.push(i);
}
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  randomTable.push(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (32 - i)));
  numberTable.splice(i, 1);
}
console.log("randomTable: " + randomTable);

$('#box').text(randomTable[0]);
var x = 1;
function repeat(){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    if (x < 8) {
      $('#box').text(randomTable[x]);
      x++;
      repeat();
    }
  },8000);
};
repeat();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="box"></p>
```

Comment: seems good, but my points is I want to run it as html element. Here we use console.

Comment: @ClassicError My code sample only logs the created random array to the console. The number itself is appended to `$('#box')`. You just have to adjust this to your needs. My point was only to show how to get the next value from your random array every 8 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

first - there is a `"` missing in the `replaceWith` call.

second - using this approach you should always end up with only one div (id=box) as you overwrite it in each iteration using `replaceWith`- you may use append and suffix the id like this:

`$('#box').append('<div id="box-' + e '">' + randomTable[e] + '</div>')`

or leave the `id` completely and use a class instead - as implied by the name - there should only be one element with the same id in the document.

provide your html markup wishes, if this one does not fit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Still not working. I change ID="box" for class = "box" - first number is show  for 8 sec and hide. Nothing more happen after this (inspector:  <div class="box" style="display: none;">21</div>). is it really diffrence between class and ID, when i just replace old ID element with new one? still one element for ID.